# Reactjs Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed an app utilizing `create-react-app` and I am getting an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** for this line:

`import React, { Component } from 'react';`

in `public/scripts/app.js`:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

var _createClass = (function() {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }
  return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
})();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
  }
}

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
  if (!self) {
    throw new ReferenceError(
      "this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"
    );
  }
  return call && (typeof call === 'object' || typeof call === 'function')
    ? call
    : self;
}

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
  if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError(
      'Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' +
        typeof superClass
    );
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: subClass,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
  if (superClass)
    Object.setPrototypeOf
      ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass)
      : (subClass.__proto__ = superClass);
}

var DecisionTreeApp = (function(_React$Component) {
  _inherits(DecisionTreeApp, _React$Component);

  function DecisionTreeApp(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, DecisionTreeApp);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (
        DecisionTreeApp.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(DecisionTreeApp)
      ).call(this, props)
    );

    _this.handleDeleteOptions = _this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(_this);
    _this.handlePick = _this.handlePick.bind(_this);
    _this.handleAddOption = _this.handleAddOption.bind(_this);
    _this.state = {
      options: []
    };
    return _this;
  }

  _createClass(DecisionTreeApp, [
    {
      key: 'handleDeleteOptions',
      value: function handleDeleteOptions() {
        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            options: []
          };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'handlePick',
      value: function handlePick() {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
        var option = this.state.options[randomNum];
        alert(option);
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'handleAddOption',
      value: function handleAddOption(option) {
        if (!option) {
          return 'Enter valid value to add item';
        } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
          return 'This option already exists';
        }

        this.setState(function(prevState) {
          return {
            options: prevState.options.concat(option)
          };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        var title = 'Decision Tree';
        var subtitle =
          'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer';

        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(Header, { title: title, subtitle: subtitle }),
          React.createElement(Action, {
            hasOptions: this.state.options.length > 0,
            handlePick: this.handlePick
          }),
          React.createElement(Options, {
            options: this.state.options,
            handleDeleteOptions: this.handleDeleteOptions
          }),
          React.createElement(AddOption, {
            handleAddOption: this.handleAddOption
          })
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return DecisionTreeApp;
})(React.Component);

var Header = (function(_React$Component2) {
  _inherits(Header, _React$Component2);

  function Header() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Header);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Header.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Header)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Header, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement('h1', null, this.props.title),
          React.createElement('h2', null, this.props.subtitle)
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Header;
})(React.Component);

var Action = (function(_React$Component3) {
  _inherits(Action, _React$Component3);

  function Action() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Action);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Action.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Action)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Action, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            {
              onClick: this.props.handlePick,
              disabled: !this.props.hasOptions
            },
            'What should I do?'
          )
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Action;
})(React.Component);

var Options = (function(_React$Component4) {
  _inherits(Options, _React$Component4);

  function Options() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Options);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Options.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Options)).apply(
        this,
        arguments
      )
    );
  }

  _createClass(Options, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            { onClick: this.props.handleDeleteOptions },
            'Remove All'
          ),
          this.props.options.map(function(option) {
            return React.createElement(Option, {
              key: option,
              optionText: option
            });
          })
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Options;
})(React.Component);

var Option = (function(_React$Component5) {
  _inherits(Option, _React$Component5);

  function Option() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Option);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Option.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Option)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Option, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement('div', null, this.props.optionText);
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Option;
})(React.Component);

var AddOption = (function(_React$Component6) {
  _inherits(AddOption, _React$Component6);

  function AddOption(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, AddOption);

    var _this6 = _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (AddOption.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(AddOption)).call(
        this,
        props
      )
    );

    _this6.handleAddOption = _this6.handleAddOption.bind(_this6);
    _this6.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
    return _this6;
  }

  _createClass(AddOption, [
    {
      key: 'handleAddOption',
      value: function handleAddOption(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
        var error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);

        this.setState(function() {
          return { error: error };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          this.state.error && React.createElement('p', null, this.state.error),
          React.createElement(
            'form',
            { onSubmit: this.handleAddOption },
            React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', name: 'option' }),
            React.createElement('button', null, 'Add Option')
          )
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return AddOption;
})(React.Component);

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(DecisionTreeApp, null),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

It's unclear to me as to why and all the documentation I have researched here with solutions does not seem to apply.

Comment: missing comma, between React and {Component}...thats what i can quickly spot

Comment: @Mosd, I added the comma and the error is still there.

Comment: i posted an answer with you code try it out...it worked for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to solve, i commented out the whole line, that is ES6 import and it seems you using ES5.

```js
//import React, { Component } from 'react';

var _createClass = (function() {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }
  return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
})();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
  }
}

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
  if (!self) {
    throw new ReferenceError(
      "this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"
    );
  }
  return call && (typeof call === 'object' || typeof call === 'function')
    ? call
    : self;
}

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
  if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError(
      'Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' +
        typeof superClass
    );
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: subClass,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
  if (superClass)
    Object.setPrototypeOf
      ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass)
      : (subClass.__proto__ = superClass);
}

var DecisionTreeApp = (function(_React$Component) {
  _inherits(DecisionTreeApp, _React$Component);

  function DecisionTreeApp(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, DecisionTreeApp);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (
        DecisionTreeApp.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(DecisionTreeApp)
      ).call(this, props)
    );

    _this.handleDeleteOptions = _this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(_this);
    _this.handlePick = _this.handlePick.bind(_this);
    _this.handleAddOption = _this.handleAddOption.bind(_this);
    _this.state = {
      options: []
    };
    return _this;
  }

  _createClass(DecisionTreeApp, [
    {
      key: 'handleDeleteOptions',
      value: function handleDeleteOptions() {
        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            options: []
          };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'handlePick',
      value: function handlePick() {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
        var option = this.state.options[randomNum];
        alert(option);
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'handleAddOption',
      value: function handleAddOption(option) {
        if (!option) {
          return 'Enter valid value to add item';
        } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
          return 'This option already exists';
        }

        this.setState(function(prevState) {
          return {
            options: prevState.options.concat(option)
          };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        var title = 'Decision Tree';
        var subtitle =
          'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer';

        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(Header, { title: title, subtitle: subtitle }),
          React.createElement(Action, {
            hasOptions: this.state.options.length > 0,
            handlePick: this.handlePick
          }),
          React.createElement(Options, {
            options: this.state.options,
            handleDeleteOptions: this.handleDeleteOptions
          }),
          React.createElement(AddOption, {
            handleAddOption: this.handleAddOption
          })
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return DecisionTreeApp;
})(React.Component);

var Header = (function(_React$Component2) {
  _inherits(Header, _React$Component2);

  function Header() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Header);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Header.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Header)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Header, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement('h1', null, this.props.title),
          React.createElement('h2', null, this.props.subtitle)
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Header;
})(React.Component);

var Action = (function(_React$Component3) {
  _inherits(Action, _React$Component3);

  function Action() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Action);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Action.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Action)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Action, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            {
              onClick: this.props.handlePick,
              disabled: !this.props.hasOptions
            },
            'What should I do?'
          )
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Action;
})(React.Component);

var Options = (function(_React$Component4) {
  _inherits(Options, _React$Component4);

  function Options() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Options);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Options.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Options)).apply(
        this,
        arguments
      )
    );
  }

  _createClass(Options, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            { onClick: this.props.handleDeleteOptions },
            'Remove All'
          ),
          this.props.options.map(function(option) {
            return React.createElement(Option, {
              key: option,
              optionText: option
            });
          })
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Options;
})(React.Component);

var Option = (function(_React$Component5) {
  _inherits(Option, _React$Component5);

  function Option() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Option);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (Option.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Option)).apply(this, arguments)
    );
  }

  _createClass(Option, [
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement('div', null, this.props.optionText);
      }
    }
  ]);

  return Option;
})(React.Component);

var AddOption = (function(_React$Component6) {
  _inherits(AddOption, _React$Component6);

  function AddOption(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, AddOption);

    var _this6 = _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (AddOption.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(AddOption)).call(
        this,
        props
      )
    );

    _this6.handleAddOption = _this6.handleAddOption.bind(_this6);
    _this6.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
    return _this6;
  }

  _createClass(AddOption, [
    {
      key: 'handleAddOption',
      value: function handleAddOption(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
        var error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);

        this.setState(function() {
          return { error: error };
        });
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          this.state.error && React.createElement('p', null, this.state.error),
          React.createElement(
            'form',
            { onSubmit: this.handleAddOption },
            React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', name: 'option' }),
            React.createElement('button', null, 'Add Option')
          )
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return AddOption;
})(React.Component);

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(DecisionTreeApp, null),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma. It should be `import React, { Component } from 'react'`